# Can we have the filter automagically denies "question about" in a question title?

Tags: feature-request, title, quality-filter

This is one of my pet peeves: question titles that start with *"question about [topic]."* The OP could at least summarize it like this: *"Difference between [topic A] and [topic B]."*

Maybe not *deny* any questions that start with that, but at least have a pop up that says *Titles that begin with "Question about" aren't usually very helpful. Is there any way you can make your title more clear?*

**tl;dr:** block bad titles that start with "question about" to help the users write good titles.

Comment: "I have a question about...", "Here's a question about...", "A question about...". "Quick question about...", "Simple question about..."

Comment: @VotetoClose except on meta... and what about a question about question marks on English SE?

Comment: Better to remove the hard ban on specific words or phrases completely (maybe turn them into an auto-VLQ-flag). The Halting Pr0blem greets.

Comment: I have a doubt about your request for information...

Comment: @Deduplicator that's why I suggested having a popup to tell the user that title isn't generally useful. So I'd say 1.) block the titles random suggested and 2.) if question is in the tile (except on meta), shove it into the low quality edit queue. Of course, the phrase should be detected at the beginning of the title only so it doesn't deny a question like mine or *"how do I ask a question about [situation] at my office?"* on Workplace.SE

Comment: While at it, "[Can anybody teach me](https://i.3v.fi/1404641916.png)"

Comment: It doesn't seem to be [an major issue with new posts](http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/206665/question-about-n-title) and with only 1292 posts ON SO meeting your criteria (25 on EE, 0 on arduino) are you sure you want the team to spend time on that feature?

Comment: @rene first of all, it shouldn't take *that* long: a simple RegEx in the same place as the title is checked for length. If there's a mach, it can just display the same type of popup as too short: no need for server-side verification...

Comment: Funny that people always seem to respond explaining that implementing a feature doesn't take much time while I didn't mentioned any estimate in my comment...my point is: Is the added value of that feature worth it spending ANY time on it by the team. Given the evidence I would say no....

Comment: [This is just not very common.](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=title%3A%22question+about%22+created%3A1y..)

Answer (score 6):

While I agree with you in theory, in practice experience has shown that this doesn't really work. The word "problem" is blocked from question titles on Stack Overflow so we get:

- pr0blem
- porblem
- prob lem

and every other variant you can think of, plus regular questions on meta along the lines of:

> Why can't I use the word "problem" in my question title?

If there are blocks and bans people will do all sorts of things to get round that specific bad rather than thinking about why the word "problem" or the phrase "question about" in a question title is problematic.

That said I don't know what the answer is to this other than editing it as and when you see it.